# simple dataframe to a complex list conversion in R

Tags: r

Need to create an options group to be used by selectizeInput widget in Shiny.

Starting *sample* dataframe

```
df <- data.frame("Region" = c("Eastern", "Eastern", "Western", "Western"), 
              "City" = c("New york", "New Jersey", "California", "Washington"),
              "Abb" = c("NY", "NJ", "CA", "WA"))
```

Wanted list

```
 l <- list(Eastern = c(`New York` = 'NY', `New Jersey` = 'NJ'),
     Western = c(`California` = 'CA', `Washington` = 'WA'))
```

Manual solution is

```
Eastern <- df[which(df$Region == "Eastern"),]
Western <- df[which(df$Region == "Western"),]
list(Eastern = setNames(Eastern$Abb, Eastern$City), Western = setNames(Western$Abb, Western$City))
```

Is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `split`

```
with(df, split(setNames(as.character(Abb), City), Region))
#$Eastern
#  New york New Jersey 
#     "NY"       "NJ" 

#$Western
# California Washington 
#     "CA"       "WA"
```